# Why UserLogin action does not raise in mvc 5

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have angular js file and I want to raise an action in the data controller but this code can not raise user login action please check this code and answer me

```
var app = angular.module('mymodule', []);
app.controller('mycont', function myfunc($scope) {
    $scope.Message = "hello";
    $scope.Islogin = false;
    $scope.Submitted = false;
    $scope.Isformvalid = false;
    $scope.logindata = {
        Username:'',
        Password:''};
    $scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newval) {
        $scope.Isformvalid = newval;
    });
    $scope.Login = function () {
        $scope.Submitted = true;
        if ($scope.Isformvalid) {
            LoginService.Getuser($scope.logindata).then(function (d) {
                if (d.data.Username!=null) {
                    $scope.Islogin = true;
                    $scope.Message="Successfully Login"
                }
                else {alert("invalid");}
            })
        }
    }
}).factory('LoginService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.Getuser = function (f) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Home/UserLogin',
            method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
        })
    }
    return fac;
})
```

Comment: Ru sure your intent there is $match and not $watch?

Comment: Has to be $watch - there is no $match method on $scope https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope